# Putty shortcut command

Tags: ftp, centos, putty, shortcut

I googled some but didn't seem to find the awnser there :p (if it is even possible)
I want to create a shortcut for Putty that when you start it, it will login and run a command called ftptop.

Do you guys know how? Or is this even possible? :p

I want to do this so I can overview all active FTP connections.

Also is there a command to just overview all incoming connections? (FTP, SQL etc)

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Also see [Automating running command on Linux from Windows using PuTTY](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6147203/850848)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made some putty shortcuts automation / ease of access on windows. This may help you guys.

1. create a folder `XYZ` in `C:\User\%USERNAME%\XYZ`
2. user must have Write access in this folder to avoid HostNotFound error
3. place `putty.exe` in it
4. place a text `command_file.txt` containing few commands i.e. `ls -lrt; sleep 10; logoff`
5. create a windows shortcut with following configuration:
   Target : `C:\User\%USERNAME%\XYZ\putty.exe -ssh Vm0000xxxx -m "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\command_file.txt -t -loghost "Terminal_Title"`
   Start in : `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\XYZ`
   Icon : `%USERPROFILE%\XYZ\icon.ico`