# putty automation using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, putty

I have given a scenario of automating winscp, putty and database verification.

1. winscp - Need to move files from local to server - So planning to do this via AutoIT tool.
2. Putty - Need to run commands in linux to batch run the moved files - Please provide information on how to automate this part through selenium with Java?
3. Database - need to wait for 10 minutes after running the commands in putty to verify in tables.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: have gone through few blogs..but not convinced to go with what is there..searching for solution or if anybody has better way.?

Comment: Do you have a *specific*, [minimal, concise, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?

Comment: Please explain the issue. Are you looking for Windows automation tool? There are a few options like AutoIT, pywinauto or AutoITx4java.

Comment: Hi, its amazing to get so many replies. Well, the problem is that I usually do manual testing where I need to run the scheduler deployed on a remote server using Putty. The commands are (sudo su / Ant run) Now, I was figuring out whether I can do the same set of steps using selenium or not? I am currently using Windows 7 as my OS.

Comment: All of the above comments basically point you to one thing: your question as it stands is too broad, not a specific programming issue but rather an open-ended, do-my-research-for-me kind of question. This sort of question is [not appropriate for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As a hint, your question should *not* look like a list of specifications.

Comment: Unless your Database has some web frontend, you can not really use Selenium for any of the tasks you described. Selenium is a web testing framework.

Comment: Similar issue described in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147203/automating-running-command-on-linux-from-windows-using-putty

Comment: sorry to all ..I will be specific from next time.

Comment: thank you once again, for giving your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver is used for browser automation testing (hence the name WebDriver), so calling PuTTY, database, WinSCP are slightly out of scope for it.

However, this doesn't mean your automated 'Selenium' tests just need to run Selenium, as it's all Java you can use whatever libraries you see fit in your test. So as part of your test, you can use libraries (e.g. AntBuilder to both run SSH and SCP and JDBCTemplate to query databases) to run these parts of the test!