# Execute Command putty ssh

Tags: ssh, cmd, putty

I connect with my Windows cmd to another machine with this command:

```
putty.exe -ssh bob@172.16.17.50 -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bobPrivate.ppk -pw mypass
```

And which option I have to add to run a single command and disconnect after that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating running command on Linux from Windows using PuTTY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147203/automating-running-command-on-linux-from-windows-using-putty)

Comment: No it is Windows to Windows

Comment: If you have a SSH daemon running on the other machine it doesn't matter. Please check out the answers in the other thread. If your problem lies in connecting via PuTTY in the first place (so you don't even *have* an SSH agent on the other side), then maybe you are looking for [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) instead.

Comment: I use now the `-m C:\Path\to\file\with\command` option

Comment: You might also want to investigate `plink --help` for running a command on another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a command you have to use the `-m` option.

```
putty.exe -ssh bob@172.16.17.50 -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bobPrivate.ppk -pw mypass -m C:\Path\to\file\with\commands
```

You have to replace the path with yours