# How to execute linux command from Winform C#?

Tags: c#, linux

i have winform c# visual studio and a server running in linux.
i want to execute this command " netstat -an | grep :80 |wc -l " from my winform interface
but i have no output and i don't know where is the problem.

this is what i have tried

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
ProcessStartInfo proc_start_info = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc_start_info.FileName = "bash";
proc_start_info.Arguments = "-c netstat -an | grep :80 |wc -l ";
// -c allows to wait the command to be execute and exit
proc_start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc_start_info.UseShellExecute = false;
proc_start_info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = proc_start_info;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
details_socket.Text = result;
```

Comment: try proc.WaitForExit() before you call read to end

Comment: You have VS on Linux? Please confirm that your WinForm executable runs on the same machine you need to run "netstat"

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147203/automating-running-command-on-linux-from-windows-using-putty) will get you going in the right direction. You need an SSH client or Putty in order to execute linux commands remotely from you windows.

Comment: Is this running on a client or the server itself using Mono?

Comment: my VS turns on windows not linux

Comment: guys now an error appears at: proc.Start();    the error is:"The specified file can not be found"     Do you think the probleme is proc_start_info.FileName = "bash";   so what  to do?

Comment: let me set the question in another manner: how can i  from my winform access the  remote linux server by opening putty and passing a command for its execution